# Нужна ли запятая предложении "Ты стараешься(,) вести себя активно в общении"?

Tags: пунктуация

Ты стараешься(,) вести себя активно в общении...

Answer (score 2):

> ***Ты стараешься(,) вести себя активно в общении..***.
>
> Нужна ли здесь запятая в этом предложении?

Не нужна. Для постановки запятой нет оснований.

Comment: Более того, это ошибка, потому что запятая будет внутри составного глагольного сказуемого.